# Using Distributed Replay Utility on 2008 r2 Client

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a DRU controller that is running on a SQL Server 2012 SP3 instance.  I have read from Boris Hristov (a former MVP that has since gone on to other things) that the DRU can replay traces from as far back as 2005.  I have a 2008 r2 instance that I have captured trace data on using the TSQL_Replay template and would like to run it against the controller to test this out in order to see how the workload will perform in 2012 prior to upgrading the server.  Does anyone know the specifics of how this works (without actually updating the client)?  I have tried running workloads on the controller from non-client servers to see if that would work with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to ask Jonathan Kehayias about this.  He recommended copying the trace file to the 2012 controller and then replaying it using a 2012 client server that is already installed.  Hopefully, this will help anyone else experiencing the same problem.